# Create dropdown in Flutter Quill

Tags: flutter, dart, quill

I'm trying to create a dropdown in the toolbar similar to the attached screenshot.
However, I couldn't find any components to create a dropdown to add the header styles and similar attributes in flutter_quill 7.4.1. How can I achieve this?

I'm using Flutter 3.13.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide:

1. Clone Quill
2. Go to `lib\src\widgets\toolbar\select_header_style_button.dart`
3. Update `Dropdown` into this "rectangle red" (The below image)

[image]

Comment: Instead of a drop-down, it will show as a column. https://imgur.com/a/twb8YPZ